EventBridge Pipes with enrichment api destination data dog can't reach pipes target
I have created aws EventBridge Pipes with full step with source DynamoDB, filtering, enrichment API destination that send log to datadog and target SNS.
At first I have try run pipes without enrichment at same resource. It work fine, SNS can publish to its subscriptions.
But when I add API destination on enrichment for send log to data dog. Everything is work fine except the target, SNS not trigger or publish. I try to discover on IAM Policy Role but it not the cause. I have changed enrichment and target to other aws service, find out that the api destination only cause this problem to target.
Sample events/Event Payload
{
"eventID": "1",
"eventVersion": "1.0",
"dynamodb": {
"Keys": {
  "id": {
    "S": "101"
  }
},
"NewImage": {
  "Message": {
    "S": "New item!"
  },
  "id": {
    "S": "101"
  }
},
"StreamViewType": "NEW_AND_OLD_IMAGES",
"SequenceNumber": "111",
"SizeBytes": 26
},
"awsRegion": "us-west-2",
"eventName": "INSERT",
"eventSourceARN": "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:111122223333:table/EventSourceTable",
"eventSource": "aws:dynamodb"
}

Enrichment Input Transformer
{
"dynamoDb": <$.dynamodb>,
"eventID": <$.eventID>,
"eventName": <$.eventName>,
"awsRegion": <$.awsRegion>,
"eventSource": <$.eventSource>,
"service": "dev-dynamodb-stream-to-sns-pipe",
"message": "send_from_pipes"
}

Target Input Transformer
{
"id": <$.dynamodb.Keys.id.S>,
"eventName": <$.eventName>,
"eventID": <$.eventID>,
"eventSource": <$.eventSource>,
"message": "after enrichment",
"dynamodb": <$.dynamodb>
}

I need to know what cause this problem and how to solve. It like no any clue to cause this or am I miss something?
